# Python yfinance: Failed downloads - "No data found, symbol may be delisted"

Tags: python, pandas, finance, yfinance

Just trying to download historical closing prices for specific tickers found in a .CSV file, however I am having issues with yfinance pulling the data for some bizarre reason. I have another file that appears to work in the same way and gives me the data flawlessly, which I will also include. What might be causing the error I am receiving?

In my eyes, both ways about doing this should work the same way effectively, so I'm very confused on how the second batch of code can execute so cleanly while the way using .CSV results in an error with no available data.

```
# Not working code ----------

import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
from datetime import datetime

today = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

tickers = pd.read_csv("Hardware.csv")
tickers = tickers["Symbol"].to_list()
print(tickers)

df = yf.download(tickers,'2022-1-1',today, auto_adjust=True)['Close']
print(df.head())


# Original working code ----------

import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

today = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

# Read and print the stock tickers that make up S&P500
tickers = pd.read_html(
    'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies')[0]
print(tickers.head())

# Get the data for this tickers from yahoo finance
df = yf.download(tickers.Symbol.to_list(),'2022-1-1',today, auto_adjust=True)['Close']
print(df.head())



#  Error received from top code that doesn't work ----------

['AAPL ', 'CSCO ', 'ORCL ', 'IBM ', 'ROP ', 'ANET ', 'TEL ', 'MSI ', 'HPQ ', 'DELL ', 'GLW ', 'GRMN ', 'ZBRA ', 'HPE ', 'STX ', 'NTAP ', 'UI ', 'ROKU ', 'WDC ', 'FFIV ', 'JNPR ', 'PSTG ', 'SNX ', 'AXON ', 'CIEN ', 'JBL ', 'FLEX ', 'OLED ', 'DLB ', 'ARW ', 'LITE ', 'NTNX ', 'NCR ', 'ATC ', 'AVT ', 'FN ', 'VIAV ', 'VSAT ', 'SONO ', 'XRX ', 'VICR ', 'MAXR ', 'GSAT ', 'SANM ', 'NTCT ', 'PLXS ', 'CRDO ', 'DDD ', 'CRSR ', 'KN ', 'SMCI ', 'IDCC ', 'INFN ', 'VZIO ', 'POLY ', 'SSYS ', 'COMM ', 'EXTR ', 'TTMI ', 'DM ', 'GPRO ', 'CTS ', 'SNPO ', 'IMAX ', 'PAR ', 'ATEN ', 'ATEX ', 'HLIT ', 'CRGE ', 'KARO ', 'ADTN ', 'PBI ', 'CLFD ', 'BHE ', 'AUDC ', 'MVIS ', 'BOC ', 'ARLO ', 'MKFG ', 'NTGR ', 'CMBM ', 'SGHT ', 'ITRN ', 'DBD ', 'KODK ', 'RBBN ', 'VPG ', 'INSG ', 'VUZI ', 'CMTL ', 'UEIC ', 'DZSI ', 'CASA ', 'INVE ', 'AKTS ']
[*********************100%***********************]  95 of 95 completed

95 Failed downloads:
- RBBN : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- MKFG : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- SANM : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- IDCC : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- VUZI : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- MSI : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- MVIS : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- INSG : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- POLY : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- ROP : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- NTCT : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- ARW : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- TTMI : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- AXON : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- IBM : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- KODK : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- BHE : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- CMBM : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- CRGE : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- CASA : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- SGHT : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- VPG : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- SMCI : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- AKTS : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- TEL : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- DZSI : No data found for this date range, symbol may be delisted
- KN : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- WDC : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- ATEN : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- OLED : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- GLW : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- AAPL : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- IMAX : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- VIAV : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- UI : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- AVT : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- FFIV : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- ANET : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- NCR : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- ADTN : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- VSAT : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- FN : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- CSCO : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- DLB : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- CTS : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- XRX : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- DELL : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- INFN : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- VZIO : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- ORCL : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- AUDC : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- CRDO : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- ARLO : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- PAR : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- SONO : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- EXTR : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- SNPO : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- HPE : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- COMM : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- LITE : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- PSTG : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- ROKU : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- DBD : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- INVE : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- FLEX : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- PBI : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- CLFD : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- MAXR : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- DM : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- GSAT : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- ITRN : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- HLIT : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- ZBRA : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- KARO : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- HPQ : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- SSYS : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- PLXS : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- STX : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- JBL : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- VICR : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- BOC : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- CMTL : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- UEIC : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- GRMN : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- NTNX : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- NTGR : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- NTAP : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- ATC : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- CIEN : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- DDD : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- CRSR : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- ATEX : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- JNPR : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- GPRO : No data found, symbol may be delisted
- SNX : No data found, symbol may be delisted
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [(Adj Close, AAPL ), (Adj Close, ADTN ), (Adj Close, AKTS ), (Adj Close, ANET ), (Adj Close, ARLO ), (Adj Close, ARW ), (Adj Close, ATC ), (Adj Close, ATEN ), (Adj Close, ATEX ), (Adj Close, AUDC ), (Adj Close, AVT ), (Adj Close, AXON ), (Adj Close, BHE ), (Adj Close, BOC ), (Adj Close, CASA ), (Adj Close, CIEN ), (Adj Close, CLFD ), (Adj Close, CMBM ), (Adj Close, CMTL ), (Adj Close, COMM ), (Adj Close, CRDO ), (Adj Close, CRGE ), (Adj Close, CRSR ), (Adj Close, CSCO ), (Adj Close, CTS ), (Adj Close, DBD ), (Adj Close, DDD ), (Adj Close, DELL ), (Adj Close, DLB ), (Adj Close, DM ), (Adj Close, DZSI ), (Adj Close, EXTR ), (Adj Close, FFIV ), (Adj Close, FLEX ), (Adj Close, FN ), (Adj Close, GLW ), (Adj Close, GPRO ), (Adj Close, GRMN ), (Adj Close, GSAT ), (Adj Close, HLIT ), (Adj Close, HPE ), (Adj Close, HPQ ), (Adj Close, IBM ), (Adj Close, IDCC ), (Adj Close, IMAX ), (Adj Close, INFN ), (Adj Close, INSG ), (Adj Close, INVE ), (Adj Close, ITRN ), (Adj Close, JBL ), (Adj Close, JNPR ), (Adj Close, KARO ), (Adj Close, KN ), (Adj Close, KODK ), (Adj Close, LITE ), (Adj Close, MAXR ), (Adj Close, MKFG ), (Adj Close, MSI ), (Adj Close, MVIS ), (Adj Close, NCR ), (Adj Close, NTAP ), (Adj Close, NTCT ), (Adj Close, NTGR ), (Adj Close, NTNX ), (Adj Close, OLED ), (Adj Close, ORCL ), (Adj Close, PAR ), (Adj Close, PBI ), (Adj Close, PLXS ), (Adj Close, POLY ), (Adj Close, PSTG ), (Adj Close, RBBN ), (Adj Close, ROKU ), (Adj Close, ROP ), (Adj Close, SANM ), (Adj Close, SGHT ), (Adj Close, SMCI ), (Adj Close, SNPO ), (Adj Close, SNX ), (Adj Close, SONO ), (Adj Close, SSYS ), (Adj Close, STX ), (Adj Close, TEL ), (Adj Close, TTMI ), (Adj Close, UEIC ), (Adj Close, UI ), (Adj Close, VIAV ), (Adj Close, VICR ), (Adj Close, VPG ), (Adj Close, VSAT ), (Adj Close, VUZI ), (Adj Close, VZIO ), (Adj Close, WDC ), (Adj Close, XRX ), (Adj Close, ZBRA ), (Close, AAPL ), (Close, ADTN ), (Close, AKTS ), (Close, ANET ), (Close, ARLO ), ...]
Index: []

[0 rows x 570 columns]
```

Comment: This issue is raised and is open in Github - find the link [here](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/issues/359). People there do have some work arounds, check it out.

Answer (score 3):

uninstall yfinance and download it again in cmd

**Step 1:** uninstall the current version of yfinance,
pip uninstall -y yfinance.

**Step 2:** install the current version of yfinance,
pip install yfinance

Answer (score 0):

You got trailing whitespace in your ticker names, which leads to invalid ticker names e. g. `'AAPL '` instead of `'AAPL'`.

You can fix it by by replacing:

```
df = yf.download(tickers.Symbol.to_list(),'2022-1-1',today, auto_adjust=True)['Close']
```

with:

```
df = yf.download(tickers.Symbol.str.strip().to_list(),'2022-1-1',today, auto_adjust=True)['Close']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the original tickers maybe, for example, the NSE stickers have a '.NS' suffix at the end.
So the index you are searching for may have a suffix you might need to verify about.